# Path distance probability in random graph

Tags: probability, random-graphs

Well, let $g$ be a random graph under $n$ vertices in term Erdős–Rényi model. There are some problem. Witch probability that this graph will have any two vertices with shortest path is exactly equal to 2? I guess there are no some simple formula in term of combinatorics, may be problem have some asymptotic estumation?

Comment: I suppose this is equivalent to finding the threshold for a graph with no isolated edges.